# How to set tag for nodes with multiple nics in MAAS?

Tags: juju, maas

I would like to set-constraint in juju for a machine with two nics to be provisioned only. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment MAAS does not support this ability. We are working towards this feature in MAAS 1.9, which will be released with Ubuntu 15.10.

**MAAS 2.1 Supports Interface Tags** - on the machine details page you can tag interfaces.

Comment: Is it not possible to create a [tag](https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/tags.html) using MAAS? There must be a way to get that information from the “lshw” utility as mentioned in the link.

Comment: You can tag any machine what every you want. So if that fits the use case that is fine. Support for this will be coming in 1.9 to allow this to be native, where charms can require that two nics be present.

Answer (score 1):

A "network" constraint can be set.

Network constraint explained:
Comma-delimited list of networks that must be available to the machine. Networks that must not be available to the machine are prefixed with a "^". For example. "db,^dmz". Currently only supported by MaaS.

juju also supports [network spaces](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/wip-spaces) now using which a charm can be deployed on nodes that have connectivity to specific networks.